# Executing two infinite loops together. 1 while loop for multithreaded server and other infinite loop for GUI

Tags: python, tkinter

Executing two infinite loops together. 1 while loop for multithreaded server and other infinite loop for GUI.

GuI window is not being displayed.

I was trying to execute both server and GUI together, and now GUI window is not getting opened.

Below is the code.

```
import socket
import sys
from thread import *

from Tkinter import *
import tkMessageBox
blue ="#000fff000"

root = Tk()
frame = Frame(root)
frame.pack()
root.geometry("500x500")
e=NONE

frame=Frame(root)
frame.pack()

text_area = Text(frame)
text_area.pack(side=BOTTOM)

B1 = Button(root, text = "CLOSE", command = sys.exit)
B1.pack(side =TOP)
print "Hello"


try:
   s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
except socket.error,msg:
   print "Socket Creation Error"
   sys.exit();


print 'Socket Created'
host = ''
port = 9008



try:
   s.bind((host, port))
except socket.error,msg:
   print "Bind Failed";
   text_area.insert(END,"Bind failed")
   sys.exit()



text_area.insert(END,"Socket bind complete")
s.listen(10)
text_area.insert(END,"Socket now listening")
a = []



def clientthread(conn):
   global text_area
   i=1024
   while True:
      data = conn.recv(1024)     
      text_area.insert(END,"\n")
      text_area.insert(END,data)
      i=i+1
      text_area.insert(END,"\n")
      reply = "Reply"+str(i)
      text_area.insert(END,reply)
      conn.send(reply)

print "hello"
print "bye"


while True:
   conn, addr = s.accept()
   start_new_thread(clientthread,(conn,))

conn.close()
s.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to start another thread for the main loop of the socket server. That will allow the main thread to run the UI.

Just replace the loop with this code:

```
def server_thread(s):
   while True:
      conn, addr = s.accept()
      start_new_thread(clientthread,(conn,))

start_new_thread(server_thread,(s,))
```

Comment: How will we start new thread for the main loop of server socket ?

Comment: Just like you do it for `clientthread`: Move the main server loop into a function and use `start_new_thread()` to call it in a thread.

Comment: Sir we are trying to start another thread, but are not able to
Can you please explain a little more about how can we do it